# Chameleon: Why is a repeating comment truncated?

Tags: grammar, hl7

I'm having trouble with the transformation of an HL7 message. Its got an NTE segment with repeating fields of type string.

ex:

```
MSH|^~\&|HOST||TD-SYN||201207031000||ORU^R01|0017|P|2.3
PID|1||0001|
NTE|||Comment 1~Comment 2~Comment3
```

What happens after a graphical transformation is, NTE just takes Comment 1 and the rest of the repeating comments are ignored.

```
MSH|^~\&|HOST||TD-SYN||201207031000||ORU^R01|0017|P|2.3
PID|1||0001|
NTE|||Comment 1|
```

I tried setting the "Repeats" field of NTE segment's grammar to 10 but doesn't make a difference. Also, no script is manipulating that field of NTE, so I have no idea why it truncates it that way. Can someone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer from its documentation. It isn't actually truncated. 
The default value of "value" is the first element in the repeatable field. Thus,
 all I had to do is to access the repeating fields via field.repeat_field(index).value. :)

Answer (score 1):

Glad you found it. Just as a general help, use sometimes the [HAPI TestPanel](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/hapi-testpanel/) to convert into XML, then you see very well how to loop over your HL7 elements. You then also know if you're using a correct HL7 structure.

In your example on the 3rd element in NTE `<NTE.3>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORU_R01 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
    <MSH>
        <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
        <MSH.2>^~\&amp;</MSH.2>
        <MSH.3>
            <HD.1>HOST</HD.1>
        </MSH.3>
        <MSH.5>
            <HD.1>TD-SYN</HD.1>
        </MSH.5>
        <MSH.7>
            <TS.1>201207031000</TS.1>
        </MSH.7>
        <MSH.9>
            <CM_MSG.1>ORU</CM_MSG.1>
            <CM_MSG.2>R01</CM_MSG.2>
        </MSH.9>
        <MSH.10>0017</MSH.10>
        <MSH.11>
            <PT.1>P</PT.1>
        </MSH.11>
        <MSH.12>2.3</MSH.12>
    </MSH>
    <ORU_R01.RESPONSE>
        <ORU_R01.PATIENT>
            <PID>
                <PID.1>1</PID.1>
                <PID.3>
                    <CX.1>0001</CX.1>
                </PID.3>
            </PID>
            <NTE>
                <NTE.3>Comment 1</NTE.3>
                <NTE.3>Comment 2</NTE.3>
                <NTE.3>Comment3</NTE.3>
            </NTE>
        </ORU_R01.PATIENT>
    </ORU_R01.RESPONSE>
</ORU_R01>
```

Comment: looks pretty much like chameleon too... :D